# stuck at 3rd level of hierarchal tableview data

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am developing app which is using storyboard and using two `UITableView` and one Label `UIViewController`. This app take data from the .plist file. I am able to retrieve data from .plsit show in first table and the according to the selected row data shown on second table but when I click to view the detail second table only one array strings I can view and can't view others. here is the sample for understating. A > AA > AAA and B > BB > BBB.

I have three topics in the first table *i.e.* Lumber Puncture, Urinary catheterization and veni puncture. Now when I click on each cell it displays me data in second `UITableView` according to the cell. Lets suppose showing me following data:

> introduction
>   indication
>   equipments
>   etc

Now when I click the introduction of my Lumber puncture data it shows me detail of lumber puncture from the .plist array data. But if I click on the Urinary catheterization introduction on the second data cell, it also shows me the first Lumber puncture detail. So how can I solve this problem? kindly help me with your detail answers as I am new to develop iOS apps. Thanks

Here is some code for the first table and passing data to second table.

```
@implementation ViewController
{
    NSArray *tableData;
    NSArray *Components_Procedure;
}

@synthesize tableView1;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Find out the path of recipes.plist
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"recipes" ofType:@"plist"];    

    // Load the file content and read the data into arrays
    NSDictionary *dict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
    tableData = [dict objectForKey:@"Procedure"];
    Components_Procedure = [dict objectForKey:@"Component"];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [tableData count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"ProcedureCell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = [tableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"Procedure"]) {
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView1 indexPathForSelectedRow];
        Components *destViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
        destViewController. componentArray= [Components_Procedure objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }
}
@end
```

Second table code and passing detail data to UIViewcontrollers UILables

```
@implementation Components
{
    NSArray *detail;
}

@synthesize tableView2;
@synthesize componentArray;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Find out the path of recipes.plist
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"recipes" ofType:@"plist"];    

    // Load the file content and read the data into arrays
    NSDictionary *dict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
    detail = [dict objectForKey:@"LumberPuncture"];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [componentArray count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"ComponentCell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = [componentArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"Detail"]) {
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView2 indexPathForSelectedRow];
        DetailView *destViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
        destViewController.headerName = [componentArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        destViewController.contentName = [detail objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }

}
@end
```

and detail `UIViewController` class

```
#import "DetailView.h"

@implementation DetailView

@synthesize headerLabel;
@synthesize headerName; 
@synthesize contentLabel;
@synthesize contentName;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Set the Label text with the selected recipe
    headerLabel.text =  headerName;
    contentLabel.text =  contentName;
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use both methods, in didSelectRowAtIndexPath you should call [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"identifier" sender:self];

In the same View Controller you should have the prepareForSegue method grab the destinationViewController

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath (NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
  self.someProperty = [self.someArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
 [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"segueID" sender:self];
}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
  UIViewController *vcToPushTo = segue.destinationViewController;
  vcToPushTo.propertyToSet = self.someProperty;
 }
```

Just add this method:

```
– tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:
```

Typically, you use “didSelectRowAtIndexPath” method, which is invoked after user selects a row, to handle the row selection and this is where you add code to specify the action when the row is selected.

This and the "willSelectRowAtIndexPath" methods are used for row selection. The only difference is that “willSelectRowAtIndexPath” is called when a specified row is about to be selected. Usually you make use of this method to prevent selection of a particular cell from taking place.

Comment: i used the prepareforsegues method. all my code is given above

Comment: You forgot to include your header files, which is what I was referring to in my initial comment.  I was just going to make sure the UITableViewDelegate protocols are setup in the header files, but I'm guessing you already have that setup.